# Web view UWP not loading files in the machine

Tags: webview, uwp

can I open a html file on the C drive or on any location using the web view in UWP?

I am using the following code but it is not working:

```
  Uri targeturi = new Uri("C:/Users/user/Pictures/Files/Forms/dac36cac-5d83-4fae-bf4f-112361b719ea/index.html");
  browser.Navigate(targeturi);
```

Comment: UWP Apps are sandboxed. So you need to use a File Picker so that you can open the file and then Navigate it to `WebView`.

Answer (score 0):

In uwp files have limited access permission. By the default the app can only access the application install directory and data locations. Additional locations require special capabilities. More details about file access permission please reference [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

You can gain access to files and folders on a removable device by calling the file picker (using FileOpenPicker and FolderPicker) and letting the user pick files and folders for your app to access. Learn how to use the file picker in [Open files and folders with a picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers).

According to your code snippet, you want to access the HTML file inside the picture folder. For accessing file in picture folder please reference [Files and folders in the Music, Pictures, and Videos libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-managing-folders-in-the-music-pictures-and-videos-libraries). Pay attention on the Capabilities page, select the libraries that your app manages. So the correct way to open the file and show it in the `WebView` may as follows:

```
 StorageFolder storageFolder = await KnownFolders.GetFolderForUserAsync(null /* current user */, KnownFolderId.PicturesLibrary);
 StorageFile indexFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("index.html");/*Change to your file path inside the picture folder*/
 browser.NavigateToString(await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(indexFile));
```

You may find I used the `NavigateToString` method. The [`Navigate(Uri)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_Navigate_Windows_Foundation_Uri_) method can not navigate to a file by path directly. To load uncompressed and unencrypted content from your app’s LocalFolder or TemporaryFolder data stores, use the Navigate method with a Uri that uses the `ms-appdata scheme, to HTML content in the app package using the ms-appx-web scheme. For example:

```
webView1.Navigate("ms-appx-web:///help/about.html");
```

More details please reference "Navigating to content"  of  [`WebView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview). And the scenario 5 of the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlWebView/cs) provide samples about navigating to file you can reference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this solution will not work because I have a content that is related to the index.html page I want to load as well such css and js. I need to load it as I load in a web browser. the problem is I am not able to add this folder inside the package storage folder because some times the folder name is to long and I am getting exception when I try to copy the file to the package folder location

Comment: @HaithamQaffesha. install  folder  is read only you can not copy to. Please check the document carefully. I provide your two solutions, one is navigate to text no matter file is where. Another one is navigate by `ms-appx-web` and `ms-appdata` schemes. This way can of course also load by js. `ms-appx-web`  is for install folder which is read only, but `ms-appdata` is for local folder which you can use. Please check the reply again. If you still have issues, please provide a [mcve] project.